# TypeScript typed array declaration error

Tags: typescript

For a given class I am declaring a few private variables in the constructor, and making some calls. I can getting a No Provider error on my typed array declaration when including it in the constructor, and no errors when declaring it outside the constructor.

This code works, error free

```
  private data: Array<MyType>;

  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.service.getData().then(response => this.data = response.json());
  }
```

Then, paradoxically, the below does not work, and produces the error found below the snippet.

```
  constructor(private data: Array<MyType>, private service: Service) {
    this.service.getData().then(response => this.data = response.json());
  }
```

Error from console is

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise) ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Array!

Is this some syntax error? Am I horribly misunderstanding a concept? Both implementations appear identical and feel like they should behave exactly the same.

Comment: I assume this is Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is equivalent... except for the call to the constructor. ;)

In the first case:

```
new TheClass(service);
```

In the second case:

```
new TheClass(somethingHere, service);
```